# Same route but call different controller in Laravel 5.1 routing

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have two url's one for category and one for brand such as:

```
http://localhost/project/womens-fashion #category
http://localhost/project/babette-clothes #brand
```

I just wanted to make one route but call different controller.
I have written the route but its not work for me its send error. See below code:

```
<?php
use \DB;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::get('/product', array('uses' => 'ProductController@index'));
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug) {
    $result = DB::select('SELECT controller FROM url_setting where slug = ?', [$slug]);

    if ($result[0]->pw_us_controller == 'CategoryController@view') {
        return Redirect::action('CategoryController@view', array($slug));
    } elseif ($result[0]->pw_us_controller == 'CategoryController@view') {
        return Redirect::action('BrandController@index', array($slug));
    } else {
        return Redirect::action('HomeController@index');
    }
});
```

Error: `InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 576: Action App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@view not defined.`

I am pretty confused, what went wrong? any idea!!!

Comment: Apparently you don't have a function `view()` in your `CategoryController`.

Comment: I have function view() in my class CategoryController. If I used this route: Route::get('/{slug}', 'CategoryController@view')->where('slug', '[A-Za-z-0-9]+'); it route correctly

Comment: routes are not meant to execute such logic what you can do is get/post data on the single function from the route and then divert the data into different functions depending upon the data passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the route for `CategoryController@view`.

Try adding something like this in your route file:

```
Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@view');
```

**---EDIT---**

I just read better the question. I think you would to obtain something like this:

```
/womens-fashion --> CategoryController@view
/babette-clothes --> BrandController@view
```

and you have slugs stored in your DB.

So, perhaps **redirect** is not your solution.

I would do something like this:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'SlugController@view');
```

controller `SlugController`:

```
class SlugController extends Controller
{

  public function view(Request $request, $slug)
  {
    $result = DB::select('SELECT controller FROM url_setting where slug = ?', [$slug]);

    if ($result[0]->pw_us_controller == 'CategoryController@view') {
        return self::category($request, $slug);
    } else if ($result[0]->pw_us_controller == 'BrandController@view') {
        return self::brand($request, $slug);
    } else {
        // redirect to home
    }
  }

  private function category($request, $slug)
  {
    // Category controller function
    // ....
  }

  private function brand($request, $slug)
  {
    // Brand controller function
    // ....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather use this syntax:

```
return redirect()->action('CategoryController@view', array($slug));
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is a public function 'view' function in your CategoryController class?

Comment: Yes check my CategoryController class code:

<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\ModelCategory;
use App\Model\ModelProduct;
use App\Functions\Common;
use DB;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function view($slug)
    {
  echo $slug;
    }
}

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822302/laravel-action-not-defined