# Laravel 5.2 and PayPayl integration for payments?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5

I'm a newbie on Laravel, and I'm trying to implement PayPal on my website.

Already tried searching PayPal packages on GitHub, but most of them are outdated, or without enough documentantion.

So I'm here to ask if someone has an idea to integrate PayPal payments (express checkout) on Laravel 5.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

So I took this package; http://packalyst.com/packages/package/netshell/paypal

And just did what the doc says, the `composer require netshell/paypal dev-master`, then add the **service provider** and **alias** on the **app.php**.

I tried the "ExampleController" given, by making a new controller called "PaymentController", and added a few lines on my routes.php.

## **Here is my PaymentController;**

```
'namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use PayPal;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $_apiContext;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret'));

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));

    }

    public function getCheckout()
    {
        $payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
        $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
        // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
        // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

        $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

        $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PaymentController@getDone'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('PaymentController@getCancel'));

        $payment = PayPal::Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
        $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

        return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
    }

    public function getDone(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->get('paymentId');
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

        $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

        $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

        $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
        $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);

        // Clear the shopping cart, write to database, send notifications, etc.

        // Thank the user for the purchase
        return view('checkout.done');
    }

    public function getCancel()
    {
        // Curse and humiliate the user for cancelling this most sacred payment (yours)
        return view('checkout.cancel');
    }'
```

## And my routes.php

```
`Route::group(['prefix' => 'payment'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'PaymentController@getCheckout');
});`
```

## And I got this error

```
`InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 603:
Action App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController@getDone not defined.
in UrlGenerator.php line 603
at UrlGenerator->action('PaymentController@getDone', array(), true) in helpers.php line 87
at action('PaymentController@getDone') in PaymentController.php line 48
at PaymentController->getCheckout()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PaymentController), 'getCheckout'), array()) in Controller.php line 78
at Controller->callAction('getCheckout', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(PaymentController), object(Route), 'getCheckout') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(PaymentController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getCheckout') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController', 'getCheckout') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54`
```

Comment: their are talking about this error on -> 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822302/laravel-action-not-defined]

,

[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/routing-throwing-action-not-defined]

and

[https://laravel.io/forum/04-22-2015-action-not-defined-although-it-is]

i hope it helps.