# Redirect to laravel controller action - action not defined

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, controller

I am trying to redirect the page from a controller to an action in another controller in `Laravel 5.3`. The error returned is:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 605:
Action App\Http\Controllers\StartChoosingController@index not defined.
```

My codes are as follows:

HomeController.php:
[image]

StartChoosingController.php:
[image]

As I looked over the internet to find an answer I could discover that my problem might be because of not having used the proper `namespacing`:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822302/laravel-action-not-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29830844/2922479)

Would you please tell me how and what to add to the `namespace` of `use` part of my code to fix the issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: An advice that is related to how you debug your data : Laravel propose an advanced function that prettify the print_r which is `dd($var)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `Route::resource()` for controller routes, try to change `index()` method to `showAll()` and add parameter:

```
public function showAll($userTableData)
```

And use it:

```
redirect()->action('StartChoosingController@showAll', ['userTableData' => $user_table_data]);
```

Also, you'll need to define new route:

```
Route::get('show-all/{userTableData}', 'StartChoosingController@showAll')
```

If `userTableData` is not a string, but an object, you should pass data with post method and hidden inputs.

Comment: Thank you all, but this time there is no value passed to 'StartChoosingController'. After the redirection, the address bar shows `http://localhost/StartChoosingController?` and the error is the demonstrated page is `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\StartChoosingController::index()`

Comment: Still the same problem. Is there any problem with my route:     `Route::get('/StartChoosingController', 'StartChoosingController@index');`

Comment: Yes, it should be `Route::get('StartChoosingController/{userTableData}', 'StartChoosingController@index');` It will work if your data is a string.

Comment: Thank you sir. You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

For my fellow Laravel 8 users, if you're experiencing the same issue try `return redirect()->action([TargetController::class, 'controller_method']);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

```
redirect()->action([App\Http\Controllers\StartChoosingController::class, 'index']);
```

please make sure that the above App\Http\Controllers\StartChoosingController::class is 'assigned' to an actual URL so that Laravel knows where actually do redirect.

Here is the full working example:
*web.php*

```
Route::get('some', function () {
    return redirect()->action([App\Http\Controllers\StartChoosingController::class, 'index']);
});

Route::get('some/index', [App\Http\Controllers\StartChoosingController::class, 'index']);
```

*app/Http/Controllers/StartChoosingController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class StartChoosingController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'hi';
    }
}
```